# Oracle return row data as columns for specified number of unique entries

Tags: oracle, pivot

I have an Oracle table that functions as an activity log/change tracker for items by their item number identifier.  I would like to take the last three changes and list them out in a column format.

Sample data

```
Item_No   Shipping_date     Last_updated
100       01-Sep-16         24-Aug-16
101       10-Sep-16         24-Aug-16
102       31-Aug-16         24-Aug-16
101       11-Sep-16         25-Aug-16
101       12-Sep-16         26-Aug-16
100       31-Aug-16         27-Aug-16
102       01-Sep-16         27-Aug-16
103       01-Oct-16         27-Aug-16

Expected output would be:
Item_No Shipping_1  Updated_1  Shipping_2  Updated_2  Shipping_3  Updated_3
100     01-Sep-16   24-Aug-16  31-Aug-16   27-Aug-16
101     10-Sep-16   24-Aug-16  11-Sep-16   25-Aug-16  12-Sep-16   26-Aug-16
102     31-Aug-16   24-Aug-16  01-Sep-16   27-Aug-16
103     01-Oct-16   27-Aug-16
```

Anyone have any ideas?  I've messed around with PIVOT, DECODE, but I can't seem to get anything to work.  The closest I've come is this:

```
SELECT
  ITEM_NO,
  LISTAGG(TO_CHAR(Shipping_date, 'DD-MON-YY') || ' ' || TO_CHAR(Last_updated, 'DD-MON-YY'))
  WITHIN GROUP
  (ORDER BY Last_updated) Shipping_date
FROM SHIPPING_DETAIL
GROUP BY Item_No
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle `PIVOT` can work:

```
with test_data (item_no, shipping_date, last_updated) as (
SELECT 100, to_date(       '01-Sep-16','DD-MON-YY'), to_date('24-Aug-16','DD-MON-YY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 101, to_date(       '10-Sep-16','DD-MON-YY'), to_date('24-Aug-16','DD-MON-YY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 102, to_date(       '31-Aug-16','DD-MON-YY'), to_date('24-Aug-16','DD-MON-YY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 101, to_date(       '11-Sep-16','DD-MON-YY'), to_date('25-Aug-16','DD-MON-YY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 101, to_date(       '12-Sep-16','DD-MON-YY'), to_date('26-Aug-16','DD-MON-YY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, to_date(       '31-Aug-16','DD-MON-YY'), to_date('27-Aug-16','DD-MON-YY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 102, to_date(       '01-Sep-16','DD-MON-YY'), to_date('27-Aug-16','DD-MON-YY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 103, to_date(       '01-Oct-16','DD-MON-YY'), to_date('27-Aug-16','DD-MON-YY') FROM DUAL 
)SELECT item_no,
       event_1_shipping,
       event_1_last_updated,
       event_2_shipping,
       event_2_last_updated,
       event_3_shipping,
       event_3_last_updated
FROM   (SELECT last_3.item_no,
               last_3.shipping_date,
               last_3.last_updated,
               ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY item_no ORDER BY filter_rown DESC) rown
        FROM   (SELECT td.*,
                       ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY item_no ORDER BY last_updated DESC) filter_rown
                FROM   test_data td) last_3
        WHERE  filter_rown <= 3) PIVOT (MIN (shipping_date) "SHIPPING", MIN (last_updated) "LAST_UPDATED"
                                 FOR rown
                                 IN (1 AS "EVENT_1", 2 AS "EVENT_2", 3 AS "EVENT_3"))
```

*** Edited from my original answer to allow the events to be sorted from earliest to latest.

Comment: Nicely done. To get exactly what OP asked for I believe the query needs to use `order by shipping_date asc` - although even that won't work for ITEM_NO 100.

Comment: Looks like `LAST_UPDATED ASC`.  Sorry I wasn't careful about that -- thank you for pointing it out.  I'll update.

Comment: Just to complete the comment chain: I needed to add another `ROW_NUMBER()` to the answer, to separate between the one used to filter the last 3 events and the one used to order the columns.

Answer (score 0):

With a little trick, you can do it in two steps: the `rn` is a `row_number() over last_updated desc`, but adjusted when the count for the `item_no` is small (1 or 2) so that when we pivot, the dates line up in the proper columns. Then `PIVOT` as usual.

```
with test_data (item_no, shipping_date, last_updated) as (
       select 100, to_date('01-Sep-16','dd-mon-yy'), to_date('24-Aug-16','dd-mon-yy') from dual union all
       select 101, to_date('10-Sep-16','dd-mon-yy'), to_date('24-Aug-16','dd-mon-yy') from dual union all
       select 102, to_date('31-Aug-16','dd-mon-yy'), to_date('24-Aug-16','dd-mon-yy') from dual union all
       select 101, to_date('11-Sep-16','dd-mon-yy'), to_date('25-Aug-16','dd-mon-yy') from dual union all
       select 101, to_date('12-Sep-16','dd-mon-yy'), to_date('26-Aug-16','dd-mon-yy') from dual union all
       select 100, to_date('31-Aug-16','dd-mon-yy'), to_date('27-Aug-16','dd-mon-yy') from dual union all
       select 102, to_date('01-Sep-16','dd-mon-yy'), to_date('27-Aug-16','dd-mon-yy') from dual union all
       select 103, to_date('01-Oct-16','dd-mon-yy'), to_date('27-Aug-16','dd-mon-yy') from dual 
     ),
     prep ( item_no, shipping_date, last_updated, rn ) as (
       select item_no, shipping_date, last_updated,
              row_number() over (partition by item_no order by last_updated desc)
                    + greatest(0,  3 - count(*) over (partition by item_no))
       from   test_data
     )
select item_no, "3_SHIPPING" as shipping_1, "3_UPDATED" as updated_1,
                "2_SHIPPING" as shipping_2, "2_UPDATED" as updated_2,
                "1_SHIPPING" as shipping_3, "1_UPDATED" as updated_3
from   prep
pivot (
        min(shipping_date) as shipping, min(last_updated) as updated for rn in (1, 2, 3)
      )
order by item_no;

OUTPUT:

   ITEM_NO SHIPPING_1  UPDATED_1   SHIPPING_2  UPDATED_2   SHIPPING_3  UPDATED_3 
---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
       100 01-SEP-2016 24-AUG-2016 31-AUG-2016 27-AUG-2016                        
       101 10-SEP-2016 24-AUG-2016 11-SEP-2016 25-AUG-2016 12-SEP-2016 26-AUG-2016
       102 31-AUG-2016 24-AUG-2016 01-SEP-2016 27-AUG-2016                        
       103 01-OCT-2016 27-AUG-2016
```

Answer (score 0):

I make an example without pivot

```
 with s as (
 select 100 o, date'2016-09-01' as sh,date'2016-08-24' as up from dual union all
 select 101 o, date'2016-09-10' as sh,date'2016-08-24' as up from dual union all
 select 102 o, date'2016-08-31' as sh,date'2016-08-24' as up from dual union all
 select 101 o, date'2016-09-11' as sh,date'2016-08-25' as up from dual union all
 select 101 o, date'2016-09-12' as sh,date'2016-08-26' as up from dual union all
 select 100 o, date'2016-08-31' as sh,date'2016-08-27' as up from dual union all
 select 102 o, date'2016-09-01' as sh,date'2016-08-27' as up from dual union all
 select 103 o, date'2016-10-01' as sh,date'2016-08-27' as up from dual 
 )
 , ordering as(
 select o, 
        sh,
        count(*) over (partition by o) - 
        row_number() over (partition by o order by up desc) r
        ,up from s)
  select o as item_no
       , max(decode(r,0,sh)) as shipping_1, max(decode(r,0,up)) as updated_1      
       , max(decode(r,1,sh)) as shipping_2, max(decode(r,1,up)) as updated_2      
       , max(decode(r,2,sh)) as shipping_3, max(decode(r,2,up)) as updated_3
    from  ordering 
    group by o;
```